# Prolog Question - Square number

Tags: prolog

I have written a set of two predicates to test whether a number is a square number.

```
patrat_perfect(A):- patr(A, 0).

patr(A, S):- A =:= S * S.

patr(A,S):- A > S * S, T is S+1, patrat(A, T).

patr(A,S):- A < S * S, fail.
```

The first predicate, `patrat_perfect` simply execute a call for the second predicate with the value 0 for the second parameter, and the number which should be tested whether or not it is a perfect square for the first parameter.

The `patr` predicate practically searches that number `S` from `0` to `sqrt(A)`, which respects the equation `S * S = A`. In order to do so, the predicate increases the value of `S` with `1` if `A > S * S`. If at the next call, `A = S * S`, then the predicate returns `true` and if `A < S * S`, then the predicate returns `false` through the call of the built-in predicate `fail`.

The problem is that at every call of the `patrat_perfect` predicate, I receive the false value. Could you please tell me where do I go wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the predicates?

Comment: You could have named your predicates "perfect_square" and "square". That way you would have noticed that "patrat" is not defined.

Comment: @Andy, if there was no predicate `patrat`, Prolog would complain and not return `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I fixed a typo in your code (you're calling `patrat`, but don't define it), it seems to work correctly (see http://ideone.com/j7fSA and http://ideone.com/SjIws).

Maybe you have copied the code incorrectly, or you have `patrat` defined somewhere else, which works differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Initially, I have defined the predicate "patrat" but I had some conflicts with other predicates so I changed it and I forgot to change the name of the predicate in the body of the rule.